# Two-way binding within nested directives and ui-select

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ui-select

Problem I have been working on:

The original problem (which only addressed one-way binding) can be found here:
[Unable to pass/update ngModel from controller to directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29713939/unable-to-pass-update-ngmodel-from-controller-to-directive/29718360?noredirect=1#comment47610077_29718360)

I have managed to get the one-way binding from inside the directive out to the view working.  But if I want push in a selection when the page loads, for example, I cannot get the two-way binding to function.  I can see that the ng-model inside the first directive is getting the data, but I tried various scope settings with the child directive and either it breaks it or it does the same thing as before - nothing.

I have a basic `$watch` function set up, so that when I push a simple object into the binding that is attached to ng-model in the view, the watcher assigns the $viewValue to the directive's scope object.  It does this, and the directive responds only by having any existing selection wiped out, even though I can clearly see the objects inside ng-model binding assigned to ui-select.

Here is the watch function:

```
scope.$watch(function() {
    return ngModel.$viewValue;
}, function(newVal) {
    console.log(newVal, scope.options);
    scope.options.selected = newVal;
});
```

I use this function to update the view whenever we interact with the ui-select (which works fine):

```
scope.changer = function() {
   ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.options.selected);
   console.log(scope.options.selected);
};
```

**[A Plunker for tinkering](http://plnkr.co/edit/BvtvrhF3dGoAPIqSDo55?p=preview)**

So the expected behavior is:

- selections from the ui-select should be displayed in the select, and also get passed to the view
- by clicking the 'Change' button, data should be displayed in the view, and get passed to the ui-select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation was that I had a directive with ui-select inside it.  The way I was able to get data from the main controller scope through the directive scope and down to ui-select's scope was by putting a watch function on `ngModel.$viewValue` in the link function of the directive.

I then assigned that new value, whenever there was a change, to an object on that directive's scope, to hold it for me.  Then I set a watch function in the link function of ui-select to watch scope.$parent.myVal so that if anything was ever pushed to that variable from the main controller, ui-select would see it.  When that happened, I would assign that new value to `$select.selected` which is the container for selected items in the ui-select directive.

It should be noted that ui-select uses `scope: true` in it's directive, and thus becomes a child of whatever scope it is instantiated in, which allows you to access the scope of it's parent with `$parent`.

Watch function for the directive:

```
scope.$watch(function() {
  return scope.$parent.myVar;
}, function(newVal) {
  $select.selected = newVal;
})
```

Watch function to be added to ui-select:

```
scope.$watch(function() {
  return ngModel.$viewValue;
}, function(newVal) {
  scope.myVar = newVal;
})
```

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/RQ0eLOu7SrVyWpRMR6H4?p=preview)